# Regular expression , re compile description

Tags: python, regex

I have a reg ex pattern which is as below:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?')
```

This is used to identify double of a letter in a string. But I do not understand how does it work. What does (.) do here? And what does \1 does? I know '?' is to find 1 occurrence and '*' is used to find more than 1 occurrence.

Comment: No, it also finds single letters since the `\1` is optional.

Comment: Ah. Good point. The question mark probably needs to be removed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unwillingness to read basic documentation.

Answer (score 3):

- `.` matches any *one* character (except a newline, unless you set the [`re.DOTALL` / `re.S` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S))
- `(...)` creates a captured group; these are numbered starting at 1
- `\1` is a backreference that matches anything that group 1 matched.
- The `?` makes the backreference optional.

Thus `(.)\1` matches 1 character, followed the same character. `(.)\1?` matches one character *or* one character repeated once.

You could write this more verbosely as:

```
(?P<one_character>.)(?P=one_character)?
```

using named patterns instead of relying on the patterns being numbered.

Comment: . matches any one character (except a newline) -> WHat to do if I want to include new line too?

Comment: @Jusrock: Use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: @Jusrock: Added a reference for you there.

Comment: pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?' , re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)  --> Is this correct?

Comment: @Jusrock: That would match 1 single character or two repeated characters, case insensitively, and includes newlines in the match. The `re.IGNORECASE` is entirely redundant however, as it won't match `aA`, just the single `a`; the repeat has to be an exact match and case is not folded for that.